# Kotlin User Input using readline()

Tags: kotlin

i'm trying to get multiple input from user and i'm using `readlint()!!` following by for loop when i go try to print those input back it only shows one output which is the last one...

And i have tried `.split(' ')` method which is kinda better than for Loop trick but i want my program more better..

1- it take input from new line(for Multiple inputs)

2- it print out all user input

here's my code and it `prints` out in one line

```
fun getTheData() {
       try{
           val(a,b,c) = readLine()!!.split(' ')
           println("$a , $b, $c")

       }catch (ex: IndexOutOfBoundsException){
            println("invalid")
       }
    }
```

Comment: You mentioned a for loop in your description, but your code doesn't contain any. In fact, the code you've shown us doesn't even call this function.
Please [edit] your question and add the calling code / main routine to turn this into a [MCVE]

Comment: here it is: `fun main(){

    var stringValue: String? = null

    for(i in 0..2){
        stringValue= readLine()!!.toString()
        
    }
    println(stringValue)

}`

Answer (score 0):

Here you're only reading one line.
The `split()` function simply splits your single line into multiple parts separated by a single whitespace.

In short, if you input `1 2 3` in one line, it will print the 3 numbers. However, if you input several lines, you'll only get the first line, as you never read other lines (only one call to `readLine()`).

In order to read more lines, you do need some sort of loop, like:

```
fun main() {
    while(true) {
        val line = readLine()!!
        println(line)
    }
}
```